# Does there exist the limit at infinity of a function $f:[1,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$ such that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f:[1,+\infty)\to[0,+\infty)$ be a function such that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent. I have 3 questions as follows:

1. Does $f(x)$ have limit at infinity?
2. If the answer of question (1) is yes, then is $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ true?
3. If the answers of questions (1) and (2) are NEGATIVE,  What can we say about their answers, if $f$ is a continuous function?

I found that the most function under this condition have limit at infinity, also their limit equal to zero. Moreover, I tried to apply the definition of improper integral
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{1}^{b}f(x)dx$$

to find Contradictionو but I could not arrive at the aim.

Answer (score 3):

Excellent question! Turns out the answer to (1) is negative. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710003/convergent-integral-of-divergent-function). However, if $f$ does have a limit at $\infty$, it turns out it is actually $0$, as you suspected. This is an interesting exercise, try solving it :)

Comment: Are you sure about your sentence "However, if $f$ does have a limit at $\infty$, it turns out it is actually $0$". If yes, would you prove that please.

Comment: Yes. Here's a sketch of the proof: if the limit is $+\infty$, $f$ is greater than $1$ from some point $M$. But the integral of $1$ from $M$ to $\infty$ diverges, so by comparison test so does the integral of $f$, contradiction. If the limit is $-\infty$, examine $-f$ and you'll get a contradiction from what we proved earlier. I'll leave the finite case to you, as it is very similar.

Comment: @YuvalGat: The limit being $\pm \infty$ is far from the only option. Did you mean to say that if the limit is $A>0$, then $f(x)>A/2$ from some point $M$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Of course the infinities aren’t the only options! I left the finite case as an exercise, as I stated in my original comment. Perhaps you missed that last sentence there :)

Comment: @YuvalGat: Indeed I did! Sorry if I spoiled the exercise... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are simple counterexamples to your first question. For instance, the indicator function $f = 1_{\mathbb Z}$ does not have a limit at infinity, but is integrable (Riemann and Lesbegue) with $\int_1^\infty f\, dx = 0$.

The case when $f$ is continuous does not hold either, but here the counterexamples are technical. See the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231906/integrability-of-f-does-not-necessarily-imply-convergence-of-fx-to-0-as).